# Safari 4.0.5 will not play any HTML5 (H.264) video

Tags: video, safari, html, webkit

The [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/) tells me that my browser does not support the <video> element, and when I try example page, I get the fallback message, usually "Your browser does not support HTML5 video."

I know this should work in Safari.  I am on Windows 7, 64-bit (running 32-bit Safari).

Video works in Safari for everyone else in the office.  (Windows 7 setup exactly like mine, Vista, OSX.)

I have tries uninstalling, deleting all user preferences, and reinstalling.  Anything else I should try?

Comment: Not a programming question. I would ask on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Alright.  Moved. http://superuser.com/questions/131706/safari-4-0-5-will-not-play-any-html5-h-264-video

Comment: Well-asked though. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5 support did not make it into Safari until version 5.  ([Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#Safari_4).)  Upgrade to 5.